# How get unique lines from a very large file in linux?

Tags: linux, large-files, uniq

I have a very large data file (255G; 3,192,563,934 lines).  Unfortunately I only have 204G of free space on the device (and no other devices I can use).  I did a random sample and found that in a given, say, 100K lines, there are about 10K unique lines... but the file isn't sorted.

Normally I would use, say:

```
pv myfile.data | sort | uniq > myfile.data.uniq
```

and just let it run for a day or so.  That won't work in this case because I don't have enough space left on the device for the temporary files.

I was thinking I could use `split`, perhaps, and do a streaming `uniq` on maybe 500K lines at a time into a new file.  Is there a way to do something like that?

I thought I might be able to do something like

```
tail -100000 myfile.data | sort | uniq >> myfile.uniq && trunc --magicstuff myfile.data
```

but I couldn't figure out a way to truncate the file properly.

Comment: Use `sort -u`, it's probably smart about it and will only use your estimated 10% of temporary space.

Comment: @thatotherguy oooh... I didn't know about that option.  I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: I think the problem is with the sort command, because you need the file size of available space to sort it...

Comment: @DaniloFavato Yeah, I think that's the issue too, but I have to sort it for uniq to work...

Comment: @thatotherguy So far so good... I'm 16GB through the file (with 3:37:50 left to go) and it's used less than 1GB of space on the device for the sorting.  It may be doing it all in RAM-- what I was hoping for.  If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`

This allows `sort` to discard duplicates earlier, and GNU coreutils is smart enough to take advantage of this.

Comment: This worked very well for me.  It ended up using negligible disk space.

Comment: In [my experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57460719) it seemed like `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.31` was *not* smart enough to remove sequential duplicates before sorting. To remove sequential duplicates *before* sorting you can always use `uniq | sort -u`.

Comment: GNU `sort -u` currently removes duplicates (sequential or not) between sorting and merging, so `sort -u` will use less temporary disk space. If there is a lot of *sequential* duplicates in the input, a first pass with `uniq` is a good idea.