# Optimize bash command to count all lines in HDFS txt files

Tags: bash, sorting, hdfs, out-of-memory

**Summary:**

I need to count all unique lines in all **.txt** files in a HDFS instance.

Total size of **.txt** files **~450GB**.

I use this bash command:

`hdfs dfs -cat /<top-level-dir>/<sub-dir>/*/*/.txt | cut -d , -f 1 | sort --parallel=<some-number> | uniq | wc -l`

The problem is that this command takes all free ram and the HDFS instance exits with **code 137** (out of memory).

**Question:**

Is there any way I can limit the ram usage of this entire command to let's say half of what's free in the hdfs OR somehow clean the memory while the command is still running?

**Update:**

I need to remove **| sort |** because it is a merge sort implementation so O(n) space complexity.

I can use only **| uniq |** without **| sort |**.

Comment: I'm not sure it'll solve your problem but you simplify your pipeline to `hdfs ... | sort -u -t, -k1,1 | wc -l`

Comment: @TomFenech: I wouldn't take `cut` out because it reduces the amount of data to sort.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, in which case you could use `hdfs ... | cut -d, -f1 | sort -u | wc -l`

Comment: As long as **| sort |** is used, out of memory is "guaranteed". I added some info - total size of **.txt** files is **~450GB**. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Can you estimate how the output of `... | uniq` would look like? How many lines do you expect? How long can each line be and what does a typical line look like? Also, how much free memory do you have?

Comment: There could be a way to count unique lines without having to sort. It depends on your answers to my questions from two weeks ago. Without your response I cannot help you.

Answer (score 6):

Some things you can try to limit `sort`'s memory consumption:

- **Use `sort -u`** instead of `sort | uniq`. That way `sort` has a chance to remove duplicates on the spot instead of having to keep them until the end.
- **Write the input to a file** and sort the file instead of running sort in a pipe. [Sorting pipes is slower than sorting files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43362433/6770384) and I assume that sorting pipes requires more memory than sorting files:
  `hdfs ... | cut -d, -f1 > input && sort -u ... input | wc -l`
- **Set the buffer size** manually using `-S 2G`. The size buffer is shared between all threads. The size specified here roughly equals the overall memory consumption when running `sort`.
- **Change the temporary directory** using `-T /some/dir/different/from/tmp`. On many linux systems `/tmp` is a ramdisk so be sure to use the actual hard drive.
  If the hard disk is not an option you could also try `--compress-program=PROG` to compress `sort`'s temporary files. I'd recommend a fast compression algorithm like `lz4`.
- **Reduce parallelism** using `--parallel=N` as more threads need more memory. With a small buffer too much threads are less efficient.
- **Merge at most two temporary files** at once using `--batch-size=2`.

---

I assumed that `sort` was smart enough to immediately remove sequential duplicates in the unsorted input. However, from my experiments it seems that (at least) `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.31` does not.
If you know that your input contains a lot of sequential duplicates as in the input generated by the following commands …

```sh
yes a | head -c 10m > input
yes b | head -c 10m >> input
yes a | head -c 10m >> input
yes b | head -c 10m >> input
```

… then you can *drastically* save resources on `sort` by using `uniq` first:

```sh
# takes 6 seconds and 2'010'212 kB of memory
sort -u input

# takes less than 1 second and 3'904 kB of memory
uniq input > preprocessed-input &&
sort -u preprocessed-input
```

<sub>Times and memory usage were measured using `GNU time 1.9-2` (often installed in `/usr/bin/time`) and its `-v` option. My system has an  Intel Core i5 M 520 (two cores + hyper-threading) and 8 GB memory.</sub>

Comment: thanks for you comment. Unfortunately, the total size of all **.txt** files is huge (**~450GB**). I have to remove **| sort |** from my command. Otherwise -> out of memory.

Comment: Did you really try all these things together, especially `-S …` and `-T …`? As long as you have >450GB of free *disk* space you should be able to use `sort` in a pipe. With an intermediate file you need twice as much free *disk* space.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce number of sorts run in parallel.

---

From `info sort`:

> `--parallel=N`: Set the number of sorts run in parallel to N.  By default, N is set
>        to the number of available processors, but limited to 8, as there
>        are diminishing performance gains after that. Note also that **using
>        N threads increases the memory usage by a factor of log N.**

Answer (score 1):

> it runs out of memory.

From [man sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html):

```
--batch-size=NMERGE
              merge at most NMERGE inputs at once; for more use temp files
--compress-program=PROG
              compress temporaries with PROG; decompress them with PROG -d-T, 
-S, --buffer-size=SIZE
              use SIZE for main memory buffer
-T, --temporary-directory=DIR
              use DIR for temporaries, not $TMPDIR or /tmp; multiple options
          specify multiple directories
```

These are the options you could be looking into. Specify a temporary directory on the disc and specify buffer size ex. 1GB. So like `sort -u -T "$HOME"/tmp -S 1G`.

Also as advised in other answers, use `sort -u`  instead of `sort | uniq`.

> Is there any way I can limit the ram usage of this entire command to let's say half of what's free in the hdfs

Kind-of, use `-S` option. You could `sort -S "$(free -t | awk '/Total/{print $4}')"`.

Comment: I think you wanted to write `print int($4 / 2)` instead of just `print $4`.